# Nodejs JSDOM is undefined inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I have some code stripped down here:

```
'use strict';
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
function foo() {
  JSDOM.fromURL('www.example.com').then((dom) => { 
    // parse code here
  });
}
foo();
```

When I try to run this, it gives the error `Cannot read property 'fromURL' of undefined` and quits. For some reference, [here](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#fromurl) is the docs for fromURL and [here](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#jsdom) is the overall docs for jsdom. This is really frustrating, please help!

Comment: What version of node are you using? Seems to work for me on latest.

Comment: I've tried it with the latest 6.* release and the latest 7.* release. It seems to only happen when I'm using the binaries download for mac.